# Uploading large file to Google Drive

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, resume-upload

Can anyone help me how to upload large file (more than 1 GB) to Google drive with google drive v2 api using resumable upload with my c# application

```
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)) 
{ 
    try { 
        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload InsertMediaUploadrequest = m_DestiDriveService.Files.Insert(fileBody, stream, p_FileItem.MimeType); 
        IUploadProgress uploadProgress =InsertMediaUploadrequest.Upload(); }
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Comment: using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName,
                                    System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                                    System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload InsertMediaUploadrequest = m_DestiDriveService.Files.Insert(fileBody, stream, p_FileItem.MimeType);
 IUploadProgress uploadProgress =InsertMediaUploadrequest.Upload();
                                      }

Comment: i tried it with normal upload but it will be convenient to use resumable upload in case of large file.

Comment: I am not getting how to implement this resumable upload

Comment: This is the only sample code i know of for C# and reusable upload its for YouTube you will have to alter it for drive.    https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples/blob/master/ResumableUpload.CS.Sample/ResumeableUploadSample.cs